# String.replace regex is not replacing `*` in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that comes in and I am running a `string.replace` on it and it is not removing the `*` character from the string but it is removing the `|` character.

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]/, "");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [global regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) (`/.../g`) if you want to replace more than a single match:

```
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "") //=> "55.6"
```

**Edit:** Following your pattern with `+` (which matches more than one of a pattern *in succession*) will produce fewer matches and thus make the replacement with `""` run more efficiently than using the `g` flag alone. I would use them both together. Credit to [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai) for using this technique in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687278/7256039) before me.

---

### Demo Snippet

```js
var s = "|*55.6"
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "")
console.log(s) //=> "55.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used a [global flag](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) for your regex, that is why the first occurrence was replaced, than the operation ended.

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
console.log(s);
```

Using `+` quantifier alone wouldn't help if you have separate occurrences of `[^\d.]`, though would be better to use together with `g` flag. For example;

```js
var s = "|*55.6a"
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]+/, "")
console.log(s) //=> "55.6a not OK
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because replace executed just once. Use `g` option to replace every match.

```
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `+` to look for one or more occurrences:

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]+/, "");
console.log(s);
```

Also if you are interested to takeout the numbers, then you can use `.match()` method:

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.match(/[(0-9.)]+/g)[0];
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [global (`g`) flag / modifier](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) or a [plus (`+`) quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) when replacing the string;

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
console.log(s);
```

```js
var s = "|*55.6";
s = s.replace(/[^0-9.]+/, "");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answer mentioned the [Quantifiers `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), but it will still only replace the first match:

```js
console.log("|*45.6abc".replace(/[^0-9.]+/, ""))
```

If you need to remove all non-digital chars(except `.`), the [modifier/flag `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is still required

```js
console.log("|*45.6,34d".replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ""));
```